# WaTin cannot authenticate in IE8

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, authentication, watin

I'm currently using WaTiN 2 to run some tests on our webapplication. One of these requires authentication so WaTiN needs to fill in the username and password for a valid Windows Account on the server.

I've tested this account manually, by clicking the "Login as a different user" option on IE8 and then filling in the credentials. I see the page that I want, so the system is working.
When i'm running the test with watin however, I see watin type in the username and password but then i receive an 401 Unauthorized error message.

The funny thing is, when my colleauge runs the test from his local development machine ( not the big dev system we all work on) the test works without a single problem. If we run it from the dev system, it fails with the 401 page.

The problem first popped up when we installed IE8, since our previous watin could not work with it. So we upgraded watin and now we're encountering this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not running the tests as Administrator.
The problem is that WaTiN 2 is not able to properly recognize the login dialog from IE8 on Windows 7.

To get around this problem, I wrote my own LogonDialogHandler class for IE8 that relies on the Windows Authentication API 3.0 from WPF.
This class currently works and allows my tests to login without problem on our applications.